# Django/Python: understanding how super is used in function

Tags: python, django

I am just beginning to wrap my head around what `super` is and how it is implemented in view based classes in Django. I am trying to understand how super is working in the following code. Could someone try to break it down for me piece by piece?

```
from django.views.generic.detail import DetailView
from apps.app_name.models import Article

class ArticleDetailView(DetailView):
    model = Article
    template_name = 'article/show.html'

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(ArticleDetailView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        return context
```

Comment: Which part of it is unclear exactly? It calls the base classes implementation of that method

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `super` method will access to the current class and call an specific method, in this case:

```
super(ArticleDetailView, self)  # Access to the current class
```

And execute an specific method:

```
.get_context_data(**kwargs)
```

The `.get_context_data()` method in a `View` class, returns the `context` passed to the template (`.html` file). In this case, you're using a `DetailView`, so you have some predefined context, such as: `object` or `article`.

If you just override `.get_context_data()` without calling `.super()`, like this:

```
def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
    my_context = {...}
    return my_context
```

You will lost the predefined variables in the `DetailView` context. But if you want to add some new variables (values) to the current `DetailView`'s context, you need the original context, and that's what `super(ArticleDetailView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)` will give you. So you will use it in this way:

```
def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
    context = super(ArticleDetailView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
    context.update({'my_key': 'my_value'})
    return context
```

Now you will be able to use your own value in the template without losing the default `DetailView`'s context values.

Comment: So the only thing `super` does for me in this case is grab `model` and `template_name` so I can use them in `get_context_data`?

Comment: The `get_context_data` method return the values you will be able to use in template, in this case, you are overriding `get_context_data`, so if you don't want to lose the default `DetailView` context data, you need to call the original `get_context_data` with `super` and then add new values to the context and return it to template. And yes, you use it to add new values and use them in template.

Comment: Hey, thank you for your response. As you mentioned, the super method access to current class. So what is the difference between self and super. In next step, It seems that it has a infinite loop when we call `super(ArticleDetailView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)`. Would you please explain more?

Answer (score 5):

As currently written, the method does absolutely nothing and could be removed.

The context data method is directly delegated to the next class in the inheritance chain.  In this case, it would mean the superclass `DetailView.get_context_data` is used.

However, this would happen anyway if the method was not present on `ArticleDetailView`.  So it's pointless to write it like that, passing onto the superclass explicitly.

So, the code is just strange - does this answer your question?

---

If you actually wanted to do something different in the subclass, for example, then it would make sense to implement this method.  For example:

```
def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
    context = super(ArticleDetailView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
    context['new_key'] = 'some injected context from ArticleDetailView'
    return context
```

Then we are using the context data from `DetailView`, and adding additional context in `ArticleDetailView`.

The reason to use `super(ArticleDetailView, self).get_context_data` instead of just simply using `DetailView.get_context_data` directly is complicated, and related to the method resolution order (MRO).  It's explained in some detail by Raymond Hettinger over [here](https://rhettinger.wordpress.com/2011/05/26/super-considered-super/).

*Note:* in python 3 the implementation of super is cleaned up a bit, and you no longer need `super(ArticleDetailView, self)` you can just use `super()` thankfully.