# Passing data with CreateView in django

Tags: python, django

I am getting the error:

> NOT NULL constraint failed: films_comment.film_id

On the comments page there is a form field called body for the comment itself, I also need it to store this comment against the user and the film.

Models:

```
from django.db import models
from django.urls import reverse

class Film(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    director = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    pub_date = models.DateField('date published')

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('films:detail', kwargs={'pk' : self.pk})

class Comment(models.Model):
# user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    film = models.ForeignKey(Film, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    body = models.CharField(max_length=200)
```

Views:

```
from django.views import generic
from .models import Film, Comment
from django.views.generic.edit import CreateView, UpdateView, DeleteView

class IndexView(generic.ListView):
    # model = Film
    template_name = 'films/index.html'
    # context_object_name = 'object_list'

    def get_queryset(self):
        return Film.objects.all()

class DetailView(generic.DetailView):
    model = Film
    template_name = 'films/detail.html'


class CommentCreate(CreateView):
    model = Comment
    fields = ['body']
```

Urls:

```
app_name = 'films'

urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.IndexView.as_view(), name='index'),
    # path('<int:film_id>/comment', views.add_comment, name='add_comment'),
    path('<int:pk>', views.DetailView.as_view(), name='detail'),
    path('<int:film_id>/comment/', views.CommentCreate.as_view(), name='add_comment'),
]
```

Link on details page for adding a comment:

```
<a href="{% url 'films:add_comment' film_id=film.id %}">Leave a comment</a>
```

comment_form.py:

```
<form action="" method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {% include 'films/form-template.html' %}
    <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

Form template:

```
{% for field in form %}

{{field.errors}}

<label>{{ field.label_tag }}</label>
{{ field }}

{% endfor %}
```

forms.py

```
from django import forms
from .models import Comment

class CommentForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Comment
        fields = ('body',)
```

Comment: You haven't shown the view.

Comment: Sorry I have just added it

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to override view's `form_valid` method to update new comment instance with current user and film:

```
class CommentCreate(CreateView):
    model = Comment
    fields = ['body']

    def form_valid(self, form):
        film = Film.objects.get(pk=self.kwargs['film_id']) 
        form.instance.user = self.request.user         
        form.instance.film = film 
        return super(CommentCreate, self).form_valid(form)
```

To fix "No URL redirect to" you can add `get_absolute_url()` method to the Comment model:

```
def get_absolute_url(self):
    return reverse('detail', kwargs={'pk': self.film.pk})
```

Comment: With this code added I get: "No URL to redirect to.  Either provide a url or define a get_absolute_url method on the Model."

Comment: However it is successfully saving.

Comment: thank you. I dont understand return super and I had to change 'detail' to 'film:detail' but it is working now.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34046887/django-python-understanding-how-super-is-used-in-function this helped me understand super